# Wall hydrant can't handle back pressure, sprays 4 spokes when opened

Tags: water, faucet, exterior, valve, yard-hydrant

The house and faucet are 11 years old, never had trouble.

Also: I never closed the lines during winter, as I understand that those round cylinders on top mean they can handle expanding ice?

When I open the faucet, and there is back-pressure, for instance, from a hose that has a nozzle in closed position, this happens:

[image: 4 spokes]

[image]

What I tried:

Turn the hex ring, both ways, without any change.

Do I need a new faucet? Can I repair it myself?

Comment: It looks like a seal is gone for the stem.  DIY repair should be possible after taking it apart and getting parts from local plumbing store.  If it is a frost free faucet and not just a faucet with the vacuum break on top, it drains water away from freezing.  If water is not drained, then ice will break/burst it.

Comment: To take it apart, I need to close the water mains, no? Does that mean the house is without water while I search for a replacement seal? Thanks!

Comment: If lucky you have a shut off valve near the faucet.  If not, this might be a good time to add one.  Can try just taking the picture to local plumbing(not big box) store and they might have a repair kit ready to go, or have a replacement faucet and parts to replace.

Comment: `as I understand that those round cylinders on top mean they can handle expanding ice` ... your understamding is incorrect  ... it has has nothing to do with ice ... the cylinder is a vacuum breaker ... it prevents water from being siphoned from the hose into the water lines

Comment: You have what is called "back flow" preventer. That is usual set up for garden hose. The interior spring has given up. It can not be replaced without shutting off the water. You can try to adjust it by turning the top part clockwise.

Comment: You need to remove the hose in freezing weather, or the sillcock does not drain properly and can be freeze damaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to **re-seat the stem**.

I was online shopping for a replacement *wall hydrant*.
One of the reviews mentioned re-seating, so I decided to dismantle and reassemble the hydrant.

It was as simple as loosening the hex nut, and then unscrewing the stem out of the hydrant. Once I had it completely out, I simply screwed it back in, and locked the hex-nut again.

After this, the wall-hydrant works as before, without leaks.

The stem looked roughly like this, when removed:

[image: hydrant stem]